# Add percentage in the right side of the histogram with legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like these (df):

| Age | n |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 2500 |
| 19 | 1200 |
| 20 | 4500 |
| 21 | 800 |
| 23 | 120 |
| 24 | 50 |
| 25+ | 100 |

I created a ggplot like this code which show the student body by age

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("Student Body by Age at ETH in the assesment year") + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
```

Now I would like to create a legend next to the histogram which show the successful rate of the assesment year by Age. With these dataset

| Age | % success |
| --- | --- |
| 18-19 | 80 |
| 20-21 | 60 |
| 23-24 | 50 |
| 25+ | 20 |

Is there a code where I can add a legend with the success rate of age?

The  Histogram is fine, but I want a legend which show the successful rate by age in  the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom legend (actually another ggplot plot) and add both using `patchwork` and also do some customization to make it good.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame(
  Age = c(18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25),
  n = c(2500L, 1200L, 4500L, 800L, 120L, 50L, 100L)
)

pc_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Age = c("18-19", "20-21", "23-24", "25+"),
  success = c(80, 60, 50, 20)
)


p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = 18:25, breaks = 18:25) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()
  )

p2 <- pc_data %>% 
  mutate(
    Age = fct_rev(factor(Age)),
    label_pos = success - (success/2)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, success)) +
  geom_col(fill = colorspace::lighten("gray"), width = 0.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs( x = NULL, y = NULL, 
        title = "Success rate\nof Age") +
  geom_text(aes(Age, label_pos, label = paste0(success, "%")), 
            size = 4) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9, angle = 90, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(color = colorspace::lighten("black", amount = 0.5))
  )

layout <- "
AAAA##
AAAABB
"

p1 + p2  + plot_layout(design = layout, heights = c(1, 30)) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Student Body by Age at ETH in the assesment year"
  )
```

[image: plot_with_custom_legend]

Comment: Your code inspired me. Do you know how can I put the numbers in  the middle of the bar chart on the left side?

Comment: @JaimeGilmartin, you can change the value of `hjust` or or more nice way to do that, create a variable that will be half of the bar length and use that as label position in `geom_text`. I have actually updated my answer based on this, See the updated code.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing isn't really a legend in the ggplot sense, but can be achieved by adding a table where the legend would normally be. Using the same data names as @langtang, we can do:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  ggtitle("Student Body by Age at ETH in the assesment year") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) +
  ggtexttable(success_rates, rows = NULL, theme = ttheme("light")) +
  plot_layout(widths = 2:1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one more option:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

# make a ggplot chart
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  ggtitle("Student Body by Age at ETH in the assesment year") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))


# construct table    
df_success <- ggtexttable(df_success, rows = NULL, 
                  theme = ttheme("lBlack"))

grid.arrange(p,df_success, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to go with a table annotation instead, you could do this, assuming your above `success_rates`:

```
library(ggpp)
success_legend = tibble(x=6,y=4000, success=list(success_rates))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Student Body by Age at ETH in the assesment year") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) + 
  geom_table(data=success_legend, aes(x,y,label=success))
```

[image: success_rates]

Inputs:

```
df = structure(list(Age = c("18", "19", "20", "21", "23", "24", "25+"
), n = c(2500L, 1200L, 4500L, 800L, 120L, 50L, 100L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")

success_rates = structure(list(Age = c("18-19", "20-21", "23-24", "25+"), `% success` = c(80L, 
60L, 50L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```